# Python SQLAlchemy engine.execute: data argument can't be an iterator

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I am trying to learn some Python including Pandas.
I came across a problem where the *sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy* is obviously giving me back an iterator thus I am unable to put it back into a Pandas DataFrame. I've spent the last 3 hours looking for the issue but I cannot find a solution. Maybe someone knows the same problem and can help me.!

This is my code so far:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

filepath = "/Users/name/Python/SQL/"
filename = filepath + "Mappe1.xlsx"

# read the excel file
df = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name='Tabelle1')

# create the sql engine (in RAM)
engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo = False)
# bring DataFrame into DB Table
dfs = df.to_sql('table1', engine, if_exists='replace',index=False)

# search query
sql = engine.execute("select * from table1")

# back to pd DF
final = pd.DataFrame(sql,columns=df.columns)
```

which gives me the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "*...*/sql.py", line 20, in 
**final = pd.DataFrame(sql,columns=df.columns)**
File "*...*", line 407, in **init**
raise TypeError("data argument can't be an iterator")
**TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator**

Comment: That's not how to read SQL data into a DataFrame. Try this: `final = pd.read_sql("select * from table1", engine)`

Comment: Thank you so much, you're my hero of the day. I was not aware about this function. This worked for me!